# Unable to delete web site in IIS 6

Tags: iis, iis-6, website

I have IIS 6 running on Windows Server 2003 SP2 with several web sites running.  I'm in the process of cleaning up the server.  There is one web site in particular I cannot delete:

- I have stopped the web site
- When I right-click the web site in IIS to bring up the context menu, "delete" is missing (unlike other sites running on this server)
- If I select the site in IIS and press the delete key, nothing happens

Any ideas what might be causing this and what I can do to remedy?

Comment: Can you stop the WWW service and delete the site?

Comment: as to causes there may be Sessions/Files in use relating to the site in Computer Management/Shared Folders...

Comment: Could this be a permission issue? Are you an admin on the system?

Comment: Seth, I restarted the WWW service (restarted IIS), and this resolved the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check restarting the WWW service to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to note that in iis6 sometimes you will have that site properties open, and the window disappears to the back.  Trying to delete the site while the window is open, won't allow the delete option to shop up.